# Flat File Connection manager does not fail on file with bad record

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file connection manager that is pulling zero records out of a file and completing successfully. Upon inspecting the file, I found that there is a bad record where data is included in a spaced out column (there is a blank column separating the valid record with some invalid data) that are not mapped in the file loader. Basically, the record is wider than all of the other records.

I expected that this would have caused the file loader to fail but it did not. I noticed that the files column delimiter was {LF} whereas the connection manager is {CR}{LF}. But, that does not appear to have mattered because when I deleted the error row, the connection manager was able to pull all of the records from the file.

This is the first time I have seen this behavior. Ideally, the data source should have reported an error, which we can detect and handle. But, a success is a success and the only way we caught it was that the job reported zero records and there was no data in the table.

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere here. What are you actually asking about?

Comment: @digital.aaron Why did the data source not throw an error? there is a bad record in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - the row delimiter was not set to {LF} in the connection manager. When I corrected it then the file loaded without error.

Interestingly enough, the record that I thought looked bad only looked that way because Excel was not displaying it correctly. When I open the *.csv in Notepadd++ the record appears fine.

Bottom line, the file is still bad because it has the wrong delimiter ({CR}{LF}). Just a word of caution that the source won't load the file without the correct delimiter and it will not error out. Setting the file and connection manager to the correct delimiter is key.

Comment: Sounds like it treated the whole file as the header row which means no records and no error.